# Javascript: invoking just the keyword super in a method

Tags: javascript, keyword, super

Solely invoking the super keyword in a method throws an error, however when accessing it's properties ex. super.constructor, everything works as expected. Is there a reason or it's just another javascript quirk?

```
class Foo {
    constructor() {
        this.bar();
    }

    bar() {
        /*
          console.log(super); 
          throws the following SyntaxError:
          Uncaught SyntaxError: invalid use of keyword 'super'
          instead of logging the HomeOjbect's (Foo.prototype) prototype (Object.prototype in this case)
        */
        console.log(super.constructor);
        //here however no problem, it logs Object function
    }
}
new Foo
```

Comment: I believe `super` is not a built-in object but a keyword, so you cannot log it. `super.property` is a syntax similar to accessing object properties, but it doesn't make the word itself an object.

Comment: [MDN states](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super): *"Note also that super.prop is a special syntax for property lookup on the prototype, but super itself is not a variable that points to the prototype."*